# Auto Generated id lost asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have been digging into asp.net identity for few days now , and I'm trying to extend and customize the Identity

I created a custom class out of everything and it's working so far
which means I Extended all identity classes:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

you can see that all classes in the User class are my classes,

I did that for UserStore, RoleStore, UserManager , RoleManager:

```
 public class HEUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public HEUserManager(IUserStore<User> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static HEUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<HEUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new HEUserManager(new HEUserStore(context.Get<HEDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<User>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<User>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class HESignInManager : SignInManager<User, string>
{
    public HESignInManager(HEUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(User user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((HEUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static HESignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<HESignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new HESignInManager(context.GetUserManager<HEUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}

public class HEUserStore : UserStore<User, Role, string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>, IUserStore<User>, IUserStore<User,string>, IDisposable
{
    public HEUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class HERoleManager : RoleManager<Role, string>
{
    public HERoleManager(IRoleStore<Role, string> store) : base(store)
    {
    }
}

public class HERoleStore : RoleStore<Role, string, UserRole>
{
    public HERoleStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

it's working so far, but before customizing this , crating a user using the user manager is very straight forward , and created a user for me in the database

but now I have to put the user id manually every time , otherwise I'm getting this error

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

is this normal or did i do something wrong? if it's normal , how can I generate the IDs automatically again?

Comment: Honestly I think asp.net identity is great, but poorly documented compared to Sql membership, i think you're not meeting the password requirements here, have you checked the returned IdentityResult error property? What does it contain?

Comment: I will check it now , but note that adding the id manually to my user magically solves the error

Comment: as I though , there is 1 validation error: id field required

Comment: Check the database structure, it a guid by default, try adding newid() to the column as a default

Comment: Doing this from database or the C# code for EF its self?

Comment: From sql management studio, make the id column default value newid()

Comment: Well this is obviously going to work, I can do that from my classes as well in the constructor , Id = Guid.NewGuid.ToString() and it did work

My question is if this is the right away , how did asp identity did it before? what did I break to have this behavior

Comment: You inherited from IdentityUser overriding the primary key type (first generic parameter), so obviously it can be anything (int for example), so in my opinion, you're telling identity framework that you'll be handling the primary key, and you're supposed to supply one the way you want (if you override it using an int, you should let's say make it identity and change it's type to int in the db)

Comment: Can you try this, make manager parameter type in GenerateUserIdentityAsync UserManager<User, string> and check if it works

Comment: I guess that make sense , but know it didn't work (your second comment)